# Can someone please explain technically the functionality of the below code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng-dataprovider

```
File src = new File(filePath);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

Why did they pass the src object to FileInputStream?

Why did they pass FileInputStream object to xssfworkbook?

Why they did'nt pass any objects for xssfsheet?

Comment: Have you read the appropriate documentation? I'd imagine that tells you what parameters the constructors and methods take.

Comment: This is how workbooks and sheets are typically initiated in POI. The workbook needs a FileInputStream to read from, etc. Next step would be to call methods in sheet1 to read/write information. There are plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: Because the relevant docs say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why did they pass the src object to FileInputStream?

Because `FileInputStream` will need a `File` to instantiate. `src` is an instance of `File`.

> Why did they pass FileInputStream object to xssfworkbook?

Because `XSSFWorkbook` needs a `FileInputStream` to instantiate. fis is a `FileInputStream`.

> Why they did'nt pass any objects for xssfsheet?

Because the sheet can be retrieved from `wb` using `getSheetAt`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun. Key idea is **reading docs** and learning language

```
File src = new File(filePath);
```

Java File class represents the files and directory pathnames in an abstract manner. This class is used for creation of files and directories, file searching, file deletion, etc. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_file_class.htm

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
```

A FileInputStream obtains input bytes from a file in a file system. What files are available depends on the host environment. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

High level representation of a SpreadsheetML workbook. This is the first object most users will construct whether they are reading or writing a workbook. It is also the top level object for creating new sheets/etc. https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html

```
XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

Get the XSSFSheet object at the given index. https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html